# String to list of certain characters

Tags: python, string, list, character

So I am working in Python and I would like to turn a string into a list of characters

`VALID_SYMBOLS` is a list of characters and `EMPTY_SYMBOL` is a dash.

I would like to loop over each element in `symbols` and if it is valid, keep it and if it is invalid then turn it into `EMPTY_SYMBOL`, but I am getting an error at the `else`:

```
symbols = list(line)
symbols = [x for x in symbols if any(x == y for y in VALID_SYMBOLS) else EMPTY_SYMBOL]
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: is `EMPTY_SYMBOL` defined? And what is this error?

Comment: @paco `EMPTY SYMBOL is a dash`

Comment: Can you add the traceback, and the full code?

Comment: @Paco, the list comp is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) around the wrong way:

```
symbols = [x if x in VALID_SYMBOLS else EMPTY_SYMBOL for x in symbols]
```

*(Note also the logic simplification.)*

The `if` *after* `for foo in bar` is for filtering, and is effectively `else pass` - this would skip over the invalid `x`s, not replace them with `EMPTY_SYMBOL`:

```
>>> [x for x in [1, 2, 3] if x % 2]
[1, 3]
>>> [x if x % 2 else 0 for x in [1, 2, 3]]
[1, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if` and `else` come first:

```
symbols = [x if x in VALID_SYMBOLS else EMPTY_SYMBOL  for x in symbols ]
```

`EMPTY_SYMBOL` will have to be defined somewhere.

Comment: `if any(x == y for y in VALID_SYMBOLS)` is pretty pointless - `if x in VALID_SYMBOLS` would be the Pythonic way to write this.

Comment: @LukasGraf, I did not know what any of the variables represented when I wrote the answer, the OP's issue was incorrectly writing the list comprehension